How many distinct configurations are there?
Suppose we have $n$ tiles to be stacked in a row according to the following rules:

Let the positions in the row be indexed by $k$, $k=1,2,\cdots, n$; and let the number of tiles in the $k$ th position be $f_{k}$.
Let the stack be such that, $f_{k}\geq f_{k+1}$ for every $k$. That is, the bars are arranged in an non-increasing order.

To help make the description a bit more clear, let it be noted that $\{n, 0, 0, \cdots\}$ is one, $\{n-1, 1, 0, \cdots\}$ is another, $\{n-2, 2, 0, \cdots\}$ and
$\{n-2, 1, 1,0, \cdots\}$ are two more, $\cdots$, and the last one is $\{1,1,\cdots,1,0, 0, \cdots\}$ (with $n$ $1$s).
The question: how many distinct configurations are there?

You are just asking for the number of partitions of $n$.  Given a partition you just sort it in nonincreasing order.

If $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$, your last example shouldn’t have any trailing zeros.

@joriki $0$s should not affect the answer.

@Ross Millikan, is your comment just a comment or an answer?

Ross Millikan's comment is conclusive.  That is, to the best of my knowledge, there is no closed form formula for the number of partitions of $~n.$

@user2661923, it may very well be the case. I was hoping to see an expression of some kind ...

I read the link provided by Ross Millikan, and I consider my original question answered. Thanks.

Notice though that there is a recursion which makes it easy to calculate the value: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem
